# A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector error in c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, timeout

I am trying to post some data into my remote mongodb instance, however I am getting a timeout exception saying An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.

**Error:**

```
A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using 
CompositeServerSelector{ 
    Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector,  
    LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ 
        AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 
    } 
}. 

Client view of cluster state is { 
    ClusterId : "1", 
    ConnectionMode : "Automatic", 
    Type : "Unknown", 
    State : "Disconnected", 
    Servers : [{ 
        ServerId: "{ 
            ClusterId : 1, 
            EndPoint : "10.0.0.xxx:27017" 
        }", 
        EndPoint: "10.0.0.xxx:27017", 
        State: "Disconnected", 
        Type: "Unknown",
        HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. --->                  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.x:27017 
    }] 
}.
```

I tried connecting to mongodb through both the options but this did not help.

**1)**

```
string username = "admin";
string password = "admin";
var settings = new MongoClientSettings
{
    Credential = credential,
    Server = new MongoServerAddress("10.0.0.xxx", 27017)
};
MongoClient dbClient = new MongoClient(settings);
IMongoDatabase db = dbClient.GetDatabase("test");
var ReportData = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("ReportData");
ReportData.InsertOne(document);
```

**2)**

```
MongoClient dbClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://admin:admin@127.0.0.x:27017/test");
IMongoDatabase db = dbClient.GetDatabase("test");
var ReportData = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("ReportData");
ReportData.InsertOne(document);
```

What can be the issue? I'm new to this.